# Listening to dependency property changes on one viewmodel from another viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a view model for a data entry view in my WPF app. Using MVVM, I am trying to account for a scenario in which there is a possibility to have a "shipped to customer" and a different "billed to customer" if need be.

My view has 2 sections: Billing Customer and Shipping Customer. The shipping customer can be automatically filled from the billing customer, or not filled at all (if not being shipped) or manually filled in (if the shipping to is different).

[image: View shot]

The bill to is currently bound to my MainWindowViewModel.BilledCustomer's properties via XAML. the "BeingShipped" checkbox is regulating the stackpanel that holds all the fields for Ship to via data binding on IsChecked property.

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewViewModelBase
{
    public bool Validated = false;
    public bool Saved = false;

    private MenuViewModel _menumodel;

    public ObservableCollection<BillablePartViewModel> WorkOrderParts { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<BillableServiceViewModel> WorkOrderServices { get; set; }

    public CustomerViewModel BilledCustomer { get; set; }

    public CustomerViewModel ShippedCustomer { get; set; }

    public WorkOrderViewModel WorkOrder { get; set; }

    //App.config fields
    public string Company_Name { get; set; }
    public string Company_Address { get; set; }
    public string Company_Phone { get; set; }
    public string Company_Fax { get; set; }
    public string Company_Site { get; set; }
    public string Company_Department { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel(ObservableCollection<BillablePartViewModel> parts, ObservableCollection<BillableServiceViewModel> services
        , CustomerViewModel billedCustomer, CustomerViewModel shippedCustomer, WorkOrderViewModel workOrder
        , CommandBindingCollection bindings) : base(bindings)
    {
        this.WorkOrderParts = parts;
        this.WorkOrderServices = services;
        this.BilledCustomer = billedCustomer;
        this.ShippedCustomer = shippedCustomer;
        this.WorkOrder = workOrder;
        GetCompanyInfo();
    }
    public MainWindowViewModel(CommandBindingCollection bindings) : base(bindings)
    {
        _menumodel = new MenuViewModel(bindings);
        this.WorkOrder = new WorkOrderViewModel();
        GetCompanyInfo();
    }
```

#### Customer View Model###

```
 public class CustomerViewModel : Accu_Base_Lib.Bases.ModelViewModelBase<DAL.Customer>
{



    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value);
        string[] names = value.Split(' ');
            if (names.Length > 1)
            {
                this.FirstName = names[0];
                this.LastName = names[1];
            }

            else if (names.Length == 1)
            {
                this.FirstName = names[0];
            }
            else
            {
                //name deleted
                this.FirstName = string.Empty;
                this.LastName = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Name.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));

    


    public string Id
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IdProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Id.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Id", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));

    


    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value);
        this.Name = this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FirstName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));




    public string CompanyName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CompanyNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CompanyNameProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CompanyName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CompanyNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CompanyName", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));





    public string StreetAddress
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StreetAddressProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StreetAddressProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StreetAddress.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StreetAddressProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StreetAddress", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));







    public string City
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CityProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for City.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("City", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));





    public string State
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for State.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));




    public string Zip
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ZipProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ZipProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Zip.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ZipProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Zip", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));




    public string Phone
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PhoneProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PhoneProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Phone.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PhoneProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Phone", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));




    public string LastName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LastNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value);
        this.Name = this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LastName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LastNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LastName", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));




    public string Email
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EmailProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EmailProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Email.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EmailProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Email", typeof(string), typeof(CustomerViewModel));

    

    

    

    

    

    

    public CustomerViewModel(DAL.Customer model)
        
    {
        base.Init(model);
        //Fills this viewmodel based off the model supplied.
        UpdateViewModelFromModel();
    }

    public CustomerViewModel() 
    {
        base.Init();
        this.Model.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        UpdateViewModelFromModel();
    }
```

I thought about setting conditions in the Setters for this scenario within the actual `CustomerViewModel` but I don't want to add logic to a class if it's logic will only be used in one view. I want to keep the logic within my actual `MainWindowViewModel`. How can I accomplish this using an MVVM approach?

Comment: First of all why you have created so many DP's on ViewModel? ViewModel should have normal CLR properties to which you can bind to from View. Anyway for your question why not to have Clone() method in your Customer class and once checkBox gets checked, set `ShippedCustomer = BilledCustomer.Clone()`.

Comment: ehhmmmm... [DependencyProperties don't belong into ViewModels](http://kentb.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html). Remove all that.

Comment: Well all of MSDN's docs that I have read use DP's instead of CLR properties. Just read that article and doesn't really apply in this scenario. This is a very small app, 3 windows at most, and the only real issue I see is that of the thread affinity issue with DP's. I think clone() should suffice in this instance. Thanks for the article @HighCore, i'll log that away for bigger projects.

Comment: @Adrian PLEASE.. show me an MSDN doc using DPs for `ViewModels` (as opposed to UI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your class **`CustomerViewModel`** I can see only fields of type string in it, so you can use [**MemberwiseClone()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) method to create a clone object for CustomerViewModel.

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
   .....

   public CutomerViewModel Clone()
   {
      return (CustomerViewModel)MemberwiseClone();
   }

   .....
}
```

And in your **`MainWindowViewModel`** when Being Shipped checkBox get checked:

```
ShippedCustomer = BilledCustomer.Clone();
```